# How do I make multiple images inside of <li> tags the same size

Tags: html, css

The problem I am having is I cannot figure out why when I target all the images within each li tag they do not come out the same size. They all shrink or get larger but do not stay the same size. The first item will be small then they all gradually increase in size with the last item being the largest.

Here is a snapshot pay attention to the crosses:

[image: navbar]

Here is my html:

```
<nav class="nav2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/down_arrow.png" alt="cross">MENU</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/down_arrow.png" alt="cross">LOCATIONS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/down_arrow.png" alt="cross">CATERING</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/down_arrow.png" alt="cross">GIFT CARDS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/down_arrow.png" alt="cross">ORDER ONLINE</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is my css for that section if you notice I target the images and give them the same width.

```
/*SECOND NAV*/

.nav2{
  font-size:15px;
  color:grey;


}

.nav2 ul{
  padding:0;
  margin-left:600px;
}

.nav2 li{

  display:inline-block;


}

.nav2 li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
  height:100%;
  width:100%
  padding:0;
}

.nav2 li img{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:30%;
  margin-right:-10px;

}
```

The ultimate goal is to make them look like this:

[image: Goal]

Your help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Your images are currently set to 30% the width of their parent. In this case the `anchor` tag. Since the text is different widths it will make each image a different width as well. Set the image `width` to a fixed size like `15px` and they will all be the same size.

Comment: @BryceHowitson thank you I did not realize that thank you for the clarification it worked!

Comment: Glad it makes sense. If you remove the `width` entirely it would default to the native size of the image.